# Issue with ISNULL error on postgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run the below query :

```
SELECT some_no, some_Grp_No, some_Grp_DESC, somePercent, ISNULL(get_diff,0) AS get_diff
FROM  ....... ;
```

I am trying to migrate a query from SQL Server to PostgreSQL and on running this query on a PostgreSQL database I am getting the below **error** :

```
ERROR:  function isnull(integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: ...some_no, some_Grp_No, some_Grp_DESC, somePercent, ISNULL(get...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 63
```

Can anybody help me out here. How to avoid this error. Should I use **COALESCE** instead of **ISNULL** because **COALESCE**  is working for me but I am unable to decide what to use and why.

Comment: Do use `coalesce`. It is SQL-standard unlike `isnull`.

Comment: Where did you find ISNULL() in the manual?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I was migrating a query from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I will update my question to avoid any confusion.